# How to access Artifacts for a Model Endpoint on Unified AI Platform when using Custom Containers for Prediction?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Because of certain VPC restrictions I am forced to use custom containers for predictions for a model trained on Tensorflow. According to the documentation requirements I have created a HTTP server using Tensorflow Serving. The Dockerfile used to build the image is as follows:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu

# Set where models should be stored in the container
ENV MODEL_BASE_PATH=/models
RUN mkdir -p ${MODEL_BASE_PATH}

# copy the model file
ENV MODEL_NAME=my_model
COPY my_model /models/my_model

EXPOSE 5000

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["tensorflow_model_server", "--rest_api_port=8080", "--port=5000", "--model_name=my_model", "--model_base_path=/models/my_model"]
```

Where `my_model` contains the `saved_model` inside a folder named `1/`. I have then pushed the container image to Google Container Registry.

I would now like to pass a `Model Artifact` to this custom container such that I don't have to `build` and `push` a new docker image every time I train a new model. However I am unable to figure out how to access this new model (which is saved on a Cloud Storage Bucket) from within my `Dockerfile`  while creating a `Model` on Unified AI Platform.

According to the documentation mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts) the way to do so is as follows:

> However, if you do provide model artifacts by specifying the
> `artifactUri` field, then the container must load these artifacts when
> it starts running. When AI Platform starts your container, it sets the
> `AIP_STORAGE_URI` environment variable to a Cloud Storage URI that
> begins with `gs://`. Your container's entrypoint command can download
> the directory specified by this URI in order to access the model
> artifacts.

However how do I rewrite the `ENTRYPOINT` to my Docker Image such that it reads the `AIP_STORAGE_URI` variable?

The link to the base image `tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu` is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.gpu).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts), it is explained that Vertex AI creates and manages a copy of the model artifacts that are passed when creating a model. The URI of the model artifact bucket managed by Vertex AI is stored in the `AIP_STORAGE_URI` environment variable. To access the model artifacts from this URI, the `ENTRYPOINT` command can be written as follows

```
ENTRYPOINT tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8080 --port=5000 --model_name=$MODEL_NAME --model_base_path=$AIP_STORAGE_URI
```

The shell form of the `ENTRYPOINT` command is used here because there is a need to access the `AIP_STORAGE_URI` environment variable. More information about the usage of the `ENTRYPOINT` command can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).